# Draw openlayers polyline from geojson

Tags: openlayers, geojson, polyline

I'm trying to customize this example:

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html

```
var strGeoJson = '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[25.094146728515625,57.51877294160811],[25.135345458984375,57.55857562213471],[25.11749267578125,57.583614274541404],[25.022735595703125,57.58508660014084],[25.017242431640625,57.633639928856965],[25.11199951171875,57.655688188735766],[25.081787109374996,57.69240553526455],[24.97055053710937,57.68873547372526]]}}]}';

var route =  (
    new ol.format.Polyline({
        factor: 1e6
    }).readFeatures(
        strGeoJson,
        {
            dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
            featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
        }
    )
);


var routeFeature = new ol.Feature({
    type: 'route',
    geometry: route
});

vectorLayerSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [routeFeature]
});
```

But all the time:

```
ol.js?20180608153258:47 Uncaught TypeError: a.addEventListener is not a function
    at y (ol.js?20180608153258:47)
    at Hk.k.Oe (ol.js?20180608153258:302)
    at Hk.b (ol.js?20180608153258:46)
    at Hk.Sc.b (ol.js?20180608153258:49)
    at Yc (ol.js?20180608153258:51)
    at Hk.k.set (ol.js?20180608153258:51)
    at Hk.k.H (ol.js?20180608153258:52)
    at new Hk (ol.js?20180608153258:301)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (history-map:1372)
    at i (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
```

**Someone can tell where the problem is? How to draw a line from geojson.**

Answer (score 3):

Your main issue is that you use an `ol.format.Polyline` whereas you should use `ol.format.GeoJSON`.

The tip is about the following code

```
var route = /** @type {ol.geom.LineString} */ (new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeature(JSON.parse(strGeoJson).features[0], {
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
})).getGeometry();
```

`JSON.parse(strGeoJson).features[0]` get you a GeoJSON Feature. Then you parse it and you get the `ol.geom.LineString` from it (with `getGeometry()`)

You can see [a working solution](https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/e254c900772fc0955763e3125bb820f2) with your code (I've changed the center to fit your sample and the background map with OpenStreetMap instead of Bing)